# How to convert an indexed image to rgb image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, colors, filter

I did a gaussian filter and the image become index. I have to use `imagesc` to show the determine the color difference. How can I convert it to rgb so that I can do further process.

**Edited** Added some images, top is the 'original image', 'imshow(C)', 'imagesc(C)' respectively. Then I just want the 'C' variable to be like imagesc image. Is it possible??

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Edited** Here is my coding, see from gaussian onward

```
% Read Image
rgb = imread('barcode.jpg');
% Resize Image
rgb = imresize(rgb,0.33);
%figure(),imshow(rgb);
% Convert from RGB to Gray
Igray = rgb2gray(rgb);
BW2 = edge(Igray,'canny');
%figure(),imshow(BW2);
% Perform the Hough transform
[H, theta, rho] = hough(BW2);
 % Find the peak pt in the Hough transform
peak = houghpeaks(H);
 % Find the angle of the bars
barAngle = theta(peak(2));
J = imrotate(rgb,barAngle,'bilinear','crop');
%figure(),imshow(J);
Jgray = double(rgb2gray(J));
% Calculate the Gradients
[dIx, dIy] = gradient(Jgray);
%if min(dIx(:))<= -100 && max(dIx(:))>=100 || min(dIy(:))<=-100 && max(dIy(:))>=100
if barAngle <= 65 && barAngle >=-65 && min(dIx(:))<= -100
    B =  abs(dIx) - abs(dIy);
else
    B = abs(dIy) - abs(dIx);
end
% Low-Pass Filtering
H = fspecial('gaussian', 20, 10);
C = imfilter(B, H);
C = imclearborder(C);
figure(),imshow(C);
figure(),imagesc(C);colorbar;
```

Comment: There might be something wrong in the process, if you applied gaussian on RGB and got single channel image. Can you show the code?

Answer (score 1):

```
RGB = ind2rgb(X,map)
```

RGB is just eye-candy at this point, you can't magically add information that isn't there.

EDIT

In your code, `C` is a gray-scale image, because `B` is gray-scale which in terms is caused by the fact that it is composed from gradients `dIx` and `dIy` that originate from an image, you yourself make grayscale explicitly with the line `Jgray = double(rgb2gray(J));`

Comment: @Kim, That depends completely on what it is you are trying to achieve here.