# Convert matlab.graphics.primitive.Image (output of imagesc) to rgb array

Tags: image, matlab

I'm using the MATLAB function

```
imagesc(my_gray_valued_image)
```

to visualize `my_gray_valued_image`: `[1024x1024] double array` with values from 0.0 - 1.0 (gray values) using colormaps like `jet`.

I want to store the output as a RGB image (`[1024x1024x3] double array`). However the output of the function is a Image object (`matlab.graphics.primitive.Image`) that contains the original array (`Image.CData`) but doesn't allow to extract the colorscaled image.

Following a similar (although confusingly cluttered) question ([How to convert an indexed image to rgb image in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225468/how-to-convert-an-indexed-image-to-rgb-image-in-matlab)) I tried the following, but that gave me a plain blue image:

```
RGB = ind2rgb(my_gray_valued_image, jet);
imshow(RGB);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here for arbitrary colormap:

```
im = rand(5); % input [0-1] image
figure;
h = imagesc(im); % imagesc handle
title('imagesc output')
cdata = h.CData; % get image data (if you don't have variable 'im')
cm = colormap(h.Parent); % get axes colormap
n = size(cm,1); % number of colors in colormap
c = linspace(h.Parent.CLim(1),h.Parent.CLim(2),n); % intensity range
ind = reshape(interp1(c,1:n,im(:),'nearest'),size(im)); % indexed image
rgb = ind2rgb(ind,cm); % rgb image
figure;
imshow(rgb,'InitialMagnification','fit');
title('rgb image')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: wow, as I feared extracting the imagesc() output turns out ot be really circumstantial. I'm sticking with the solution from Louis Mendo, but thanks for showing how it works.

Comment: well if you do have the `imagesc` input it makes things easier :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ind2rgb`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html) to convert an intensity image into RGB using a colormap of your choice; but make sure that *the range of the input is from `1` to the number of colors in the colormap*. This is because `ind2rgb` maps value `1` to the first color, `2` to the second etc.

```
im = rand(5,5); % example intensity image
cmap = jet(256); % desired colormap
result = ind2rgb(ceil(size(cmap,1)*im), cmap);
```

The reason why you are getting a blue image is that `ind2rgb` clips the values of the input image to the range from `1` to the number of colors in the colormap. So, if the input image has values between `0` and `1` they are all mapped to `1`, that is, to the first color in the colormap.

Comment: Aye, thanks for the explanation, that is an elegant solution and I'm going to use that one :) - going to mark the other solution as accepted though, as it answers better to the title of the question (extracting the image from the output of the imagesc() function).

Comment: Yes, I totally agree :-)