# MATLAB: Convert imagesc() RESULT to an image

Tags: image, matlab

Let say we have grayscale image `im`:

[image]

And use `imagesc(im)` to get:
[image]

With code:

```
im = rgb2gray(im2single(imread('tesla.jpg'))); % get image
h = imagesc(log(abs(fftshift(fft2(im))))); % imagesc handle
```

How can one convert the intensity graphic `h` (2nd image) to a standard RGB image (2x2 float matrix that one can manipulate, crop, etc) in matlab?

I don't need the axes, numbers or tics of the intensity image, I only need to maintain the color.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert matlab.graphics.primitive.Image (output of imagesc) to rgb array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227585/convert-matlab-graphics-primitive-image-output-of-imagesc-to-rgb-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%turn off the axes
axis off
%save the image
saveas(h,'test.png')
%read the saved image
im_fft = imread('test.png');
%remove white border
sum_img = sum(im_fft,3); sum_img(sum_img(:) ~= 255*3) = 0; sum_img = logical(sum_img);
im_fft = im_fft(~all(sum_img,2), ~all(sum_img,1),:);
%Done!
figure, imshow(im_fft)
```

The resulting image can be used only for presentations/illustrations, not for analysis - quantization and sampling corrupts it significantly